# How to verify if a button is enabled and disabled in Webdriver Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried using the following from another post

```
driver.find_element_by_name("sub_activate").click().is_enabled()
```

but got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_enabled'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You don't need to call `click()`. Just find the element and call [`is_enabled()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_enabled) on it:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("sub_activate")
print element.is_enabled()
```

FYI, `click()` is a method on a `WebElement`, it returns `None`.

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("sub_activate")
prop = element.get_property('disabled')
print (prop)

>>>> False
```

Returns 'true' if enabled 'element.get_property('enabled')

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `is_enabled()` on the `click()` result (None).

Instead, you should first get the element, check if it `is_enabled()` then try the `click()` (if that is what you are trying to do).

Take a [look at the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) for the methods on the `webelement`.

```
is_enabled()
    Whether the element is enabled.

click()
    Clicks the element.
```

For example:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("myId")
if elem.is_enabled():
    elem.click()
else:
    pass # whatever logic to handle...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ButtonId"));

Assert.AreEqual(false, button.Enabled); /*Validates whether the button is Disabled*/

Assert.AreEqual(true, button.Enabled); /*Validates whether the button is Enabled*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_name("sub_activate").click().is_enabled()
```

In the above method you have used click() method. Without using it you can verify whether a button is disabled or enabled. It returns a Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this one also:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElementById("Disable Element Id").isEnabled());
```

It worked fine in my case.